# how i can include library in asp.net project on the server without visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a small asp.net application writed in Visual Studio 2005.
Project working in VS, but not working in IIS on remote server.
compilation error CS0246: cannot find typename or namespace

I just copy the files from project to project IIS.

Googled, I found a link http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-122281.html

> The problem is that VS2005's ASP.NET web site projects are bogus....

Any ideas?
how I can include library in asp.net project on the server without visual studio?

Correct answer in the comments @dbaseman

Comment: please mark this question as answered if the problem is solved now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just place the .DLL file under the *bin* folder in your application.  Make sure you've run "convert to application" on the folder in IIS, also.

The above should work perfectly well; you can also install the DLL in the Global Assembly Cache, using *[gacutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)*.  That will make the library available to all applications on the server.

Comment: dll in bin folder. tell me please how i can correct convert to application? website folder -> properties -> directory tab  -> scripts and executable files.

Comment: @gelezko Do you have access to IIS manager?  That's the easiest way.  Right click on your website and then "Add Application".  Alternatively, right click on the folder and then "Convert to Application".

Comment: @gelezko actually, sorry, which version of IIS are you running?

Comment: @gelezko try Google, this shouldn't be too difficult.  Eg:  http://www.tamilcodes.com/document.aspx?content=Tutorials&id=42

Comment: =) i wrote:  website folder -> properties -> directory tab -> scripts and executable files

Comment: @gelezko ha, just looked at the link.  That's funny.

Comment: Hi. I compile my project in new Visual Studio 2010 Web Developer. Copy: Debug->Copy Web site and deploy this files on the server.Its work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed .NET framework on the server machine? If no, then you must install the version of .NET framework. Also make sure that you have packaged and published the project correctly.